# A word or neologism for doing an action together

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

This is for a community initiative. I initially thought of pan-action but this would have more to do with the idea of something global or widespread. Also, con-action doesn't sound right with the alternative meaning of the "con" particule. Do you have any suggestions in terms of a word or perhaps short paraphrase ?

Comment: Why not teamwork?

Comment: You're asking for a neologism? That makes it pretty open-ended, anyone could make up anything. But how about 'crowdsource'? I guess its specific meaning is probably not what you're after.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't like **[collaboration](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/collaboration)**, you could try one of its [synonyms](http://thesaurus.com/browse/collaboration?s=t), like *team effort*.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a neologism, I'm game to coin something. I am trying to tie in your sketch of a concept with the trend in newly minted combinations. I came up with "crowd-burst".

Comment: It should then follow that the use of shills in the crowd (to promote joint action) would become 'crowd-seeding'. I like it. :|